# Android Navigation library doesn't open deeplink

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Can't open the deeplink URL.
Here is the code I used

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginActivity">
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/passwordCreateActivity"
        android:name=".PasswordCreateActivity"
        android:label="password_create_activity"
        tools:layout="@layout/password_create_activity">
        <deepLink
            app:uri="www.example.com/auth/activate/{token}" />
    </activity>
</navigation>
```

I have used the intent to open the deeplink

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "www.example.com/auth/activate/2i8haFs4NqxFdzRUYoYJbq1C0?check-scheme=1" com.example.app
```

dependency

```
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha02'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: Aren't you missing http: / https: in front of that URL?

Comment: @AuriRahimzadeh to accept both the http and https we need to keep www instead of http/https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have forgotten to register `nav_graph` in AndroidManifest file. 
Here is the full code for the Deep Link.

`nav_graph.xml`

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginActivity">

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/passwordCreateActivity"
        android:name=".PasswordCreateActivity"
        android:label="password_create_activity"
        tools:layout="@layout/password_create_activity">

        <deepLink app:uri="www.example.com/auth/activate/{token}" />
    </activity>
</navigation>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<activity android:name=".PasswordCreateActivity">
       <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/app_nav" />
</activity>
```

Comment: greate idea yeh!